# 404 error with Spring

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I'm getting a 404 on my spring project and I don't really understand what's going on. Here's the controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController extends AbstractCloudController {

    private final EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestController(EquipmentRepository er) {
        equipmentRepository = er;   
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/") String renderIndex() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

And my WebConfig.java:

```
@Configuration

@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

@Bean  
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {  
  UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();  
  resolver.setPrefix("/static/html");  
  resolver.setSuffix(".html");
  resolver.setCache(false);
  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
  return resolver;  
}
```

}

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div class="outer">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is a test page</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the index() method from the controller, index.html is rendered with no problems. Also, if I change the RequestMapping annotation to `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)`, I get a Circular view path error instead of a 404.

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: Yes, I'm using spring boot

Answer (score -2):

I guess you problem with your `@RequestMapping`
Try this one may be it will help you,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderIndex() {
    return index;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what OP presented above? What was the problem you "guessed"?